# Append a column with an ULID to an existing MySQL table

Tags: mysql, ulid

I'm trying to append a column with an ULID to an existing MySQL table. I know how to do it with a function and an update query:

```
delimiter //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ulid//
CREATE FUNCTION ulid () RETURNS CHAR(26) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE s_hex CHAR(32);
SET s_hex = LPAD(HEX(CONCAT(UNHEX(CONV(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4))*1000), 10, 16)), RANDOM_BYTES(10))), 32, '0');
RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(LPAD(CONV(SUBSTRING(s_hex, 1, 2), 16, 32), 2, '0'), LPAD(CONV(SUBSTRING(s_hex, 3, 15), 16, 32), 12, '0'), LPAD(CONV(SUBSTRING(s_hex, 18, 15), 16, 32), 12, '0')), 'V', 'Z'), 'U', 'Y'), 'T', 'X'), 'S', 'W'), 'R', 'V'), 'Q', 'T'), 'P', 'S'), 'O', 'R'), 'N', 'Q'), 'M', 'P'), 'L', 'N'), 'K', 'M'), 'J', 'K'), 'I', 'J');
END//
delimiter;

UPDATE mytable SET new_id=(SELECT ulid());
```

However, I'd need to do it with a single query. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are using the value for `s_hex` 3 times in your final expression, and even if it contains a random value, you can just literally reuse the formula for `s_hex` 3 times in your final formula:

```
UPDATE mytable SET new_id = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( ...
  LPAD(CONV(SUBSTRING(  LPAD(HEX(..., 32, '0')  , 1, 2), 16, 32), 2, '0'),
  LPAD(CONV(SUBSTRING(  LPAD(HEX(..., 32, '0')  , 3, 15), 16, 32), 12, '0'), 
  LPAD(CONV(SUBSTRING(  LPAD(HEX(..., 32, '0')  , 18, 15), 16, 32), 12, '0')
), 'V', 'Z')..., 'I', 'J');
```

The `random_bytes()`-function will return different values for the 3 parts, but since there is no overlap, and all random values are valid, the whole result is still valid (e.g. if substring 2 uses the first 2 letters of a random string `ABCDEF` and substring 3 uses the last 4 letters of a random string `123456`, it is the same as if the original random string had been `AB3456`).

The final expression is long and not nice to look at, but works. If you want (and have the time), you can simplify it further, e.g. `SUBSTRING(s_hex, 1, 2)` is `01` for the next 10 years, and `02` after that, so you do not need to use the full expression for that.